# Graphic component for Text (as Ellipse2D, Line2D, etc)

Tags: java, text, textarea, awt, graphics2d

everything is in the title, is there a graphic (awt) component as Ellispe2D or Rectangle2D for the text? (preferably editable as a textarea).

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Huh?  Can you explain that in different words, and link to an image of how you visualize this component?

Comment: Actually, i would like something as the text tool in Paint (for Windows). You create it wherever you want, you can add/modify/delete the text in it, and move it as you want. Is there an easy way to do that? Thx

Comment: *"i would like something as the text tool in Paint (for Windows)"* So basically, styled text with line wrap within a floating, resizable, draggable box with transparent BG.  What does this have to do with `Ellipse2D`?  Do you intend to combine the text with drawn elements?

Comment: Well, the thing is: this is a kind of add-on for a more sophisticated programm. On one hand i have a "floating, resizable, draggable box", and in the other some classes which implement graphic Java components: Ellipse2D, Rectangle2D... I just thought a similar component for text would make the thing easy to me, but any graphic editable box for text would be all right! 
I tried with a jTextarea, but:
- i have to add it to my jPanel, it's problematic cause i just "draw" the other component (there is no jPanel.add(component))
- i can't drag it, 'cause when I click on it, he gains the focus 
Thx!

Comment: Sorry for my english, it's not my native language...